Do you generally need permission to edit?
I edited an answer I received to make it actually answer my question, as it solely answered an aspect I said I was not looking for. I literally only added a sentence and changed a few words in the 1st sentence.
My edits were rejected twice and on the 2nd rejection, one rejector stated defacement as the rejection reason. I asked how was it defacing and they said it was because I did it without permission. I then told them many of my posts have been edited by others and with one exception, I do not undue them. Then said I was breaking rules.
I was under the impression as long as major changes were not being made, that you needed no permission for editing. Is this true?

Oo, a good question of community practice and expectations!

This question is similar to: Is it okay to edit?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Generally No ... but

No Permission Needed Here.  --- Generally speaking, editing is expected on any SE forum. We can always edit questions and answers for basic things like spelling answers, grammar, language, formatting, to improve sense or comprehensibility and in general to make a Q or A look cool. We encourage members to edit out "needless verbiage" --- things like snark, personal insults, personal introductions and thank yous. We also encourage edits that update and improve an answer due to new discoveries, newly revealed information, or the like.

Other forums expect members to extirpate things like opinions, counterfactuals, outdated scientific data, etc.

Don't Do it Here.  --- One expectation of the WB.SE community is that we ask people to "respect the response" and the work of the respondent. This work often involves research, analysis, creative writing and composition above and beyond what you might find on a science forum. Very frequently you'll find answers that are highly creative and "in world" if you will. While the answers are shared here, they are also the intellectual property of the respondent. This is why we have a strong policy against drastically editing questions once they have answers: the edit has a good chance of invalidating the answer. Also why we look askance at the reworking of someone else's answer to suit one's own needs. Changing the substance of an answer makes it, in part, your own work and that's essentially a kind of intellectual property theft.

How to Do it.  --- The best practice, if we feel that an answer doesn't quite suit but could if only the respondent had said X, Y & Zed!, is to engage with the other person. Express that the answer doesn't quite fit; did you consider this; would you mind editing with this other thing in mind.

If you do edit someone's answer, and it's more than just spelling or grammar, perhaps it's for a factual error or some fundamental misunderstanding of your world or setting, always write a comment explaining what you did and be courteous about them reverting the edits.

Last but not least, while it is very poor form for someone to answer their own question, it is technically not disallowed either by SE or by WB.SE policy. Just don't mess around with someone else's answer!

A Two Way Street.  --- You mention that folks have edited your questions. We have largely the same expectations for editing questions as we do answers. Anyone can edit your question for spelling, grammar, etc. No one should ever edit your question for stylistic reasons, like if you write from an "in world" perspective. Questions written in this style are often pretty good and are always fun to answer!

No respondent should ever edit your question to suit their own answer. First, it's not the question you asked; and second, that edit might invalidate someone else's answer!

No respondent should ever edit your question in order to ask their own question. These sorts of edits would fall under defacement or vandalism.

Would someone making my question more gender inclusive count as vandalism? It happened but I changed most of back.

@ConanHighwoods --- Yes, I would consider that vandalism. I couldn't find the question you're referring to, though, so can't really comment more specifically. Essentially, you can fix my spelling mistakes, but don't dictate my language kind of thing.

Out of the 4 reviews that your proposed edit received, 3 were "The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing." and 1 was "the edit is deliberately destructive" (I am ruling out the other part of the reject reason stating that it promoted a product or a service).
While I concur that the lone reason might be too harsh, there seems to be consensus among the reviewers that your edit did not improve the quality of the post. Edits should not only not make a U turn to the post, but also should add some value to it.
In the specific of your case, your edit was just making explicit an implicit statement: by being told that your proposal is not economically feasible unless certain conditions apply, the answer is not challenging (and therefore implicitly affirming) the technical feasibility.
Compare

can I bake a pizza using only ice cubes?
can I bake a pizza using only matches?

The first one is a technical no, the second one is an economical no.
The reviewers did not see this as adding value to the post and therefore rejected it.
